# How to point to sound files that are in assetpack\src\main\assets and not in app\src\main\res\raw

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I completed my first app and could not publish it because the file size was to big (lots of sound files). I followed the Play Asset Delivery (https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery/build-native-java) and it looks I got everything configured correctly (it builds and app loads but no sounds) but need help pointing to the sound files in the code. The sound files were in res>raw are now in assetpack\src\main\assets

When the sound files were in res>raw. I used this code to point to the sound file

```
if (sound == 1) { mp = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, R.raw.sound_1) }
```

Now I cannot point to the sound files in assets and I think its because it does not see it or knows that the folder exist.

When I change the left panel view to Project I see the list below and assetpack is there

Project

App name

- .gradle
- .idea
- app
- assetpack
- build
- gradle
- play-core-native-sdk
  other files

When I change the left panel view to Android I see the below list and assetpack is not part of it

Android

app

- manifests
- java
- java (generated)
- cpp
- res
- raw

I don't understand how this works and tried searching here and google with no help

Can you help me point to assetpack\src\main\assets sound files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to play a specific audio file `(i.e your_file.mp3)` in your assets folder with:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd("your_file.mp3");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I could not get this to work. The code is in Java and my app is in Kotlin. I tried to convert the code but could not get this to work.